# Which html container allows that when you hide a vertical item the subsequents go up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

My application has a **vertical** menu. Each menu is a linkbutton. Those linkbuttons are placed within an html **table cell** `<td>` and I create and placed them **at the ASP.NET code behind.**

For creating a menu I do `menuCell.Controls.Add(newMenu);`
When I clic a link that has sumenus this are showed below the main linkbutton:

[image]

When I click again it, the submenus must hide but the place taken by them keeps staying there. I do it with jquery:

```
function toggleSubMenu(smenu) {
        $('.'+smenu').toggle();
    }
```

Take a look at the blank space bewteen Menu2 and Menu 3.

[image]

So the main objective is to remove this space.
Is there any Asp.NET place holder or container that makes it automatically? Or do I have to go up the Menu3 and all below it by hand using jQuery?

The complete html code: **MenuCell** keeps the menus. Again, each menu is created and placed at the ASP.NET code behind.

```
<body MS_POSITIONING="Gridlayout">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <form id="Menu" method="post" runat="server">
        <table id="mainTable" style="Z-INDEX: 101; LEFT: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px" tabIndex="-1" height="800" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0" runat="server" width="125px">
            <tr align="left">
                <td style="WIDTH: 125px" tabIndex="-1" vAlign="bottom" align="middle" colSpan="2" height="55"><IMG id="imgLogo" tabIndex="-1" height="50" width="50" align="middle" border="0" runat="server">&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <TR>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 125px" vAlign="top" align="middle"></TD>
                <TD vAlign="top" align="left" colSpan="1" rowSpan="2"><IMG id="imgLine" style="WIDTH: 1px" height="720" hspace="0" width="1" vspace="0" border="0" runat="server"></TD>
            </TR>
            <tr align="left">
                <td id="menuCell" style="WIDTH: 125px" tabIndex="-1" vAlign="top" align="left" height="740" runat="server"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

I cannot put the whole rendered code because privacy polices but each menu and submenu link is rendered as `<a>` within the `<td>`named `menuCell`:

The rendered code is:

```
  <td id="menuCell" style="WIDTH: 125px" tabIndex="-1" valign="top" align="left" height="740">
    <a id="Menu1" style="width:124px;LEFT:1px;TOP:8px;POSITION:relative;">Menu1</a>
   <br />
   <a id="Menu6" style="width:124px;LEFT:1px;TOP:11px;POSITION:relative;">Menu6</a>
   <br />
```

Comment: Why are you using a table for your menu? It seems that a standard list will fits there...

Comment: Relative positions will do the trick. If the submenu does not occupy the space anymore the relative items underneath will go up too.

Comment: If using a table, you need to hide the `<tr>`, but as Samuel Caillerie said, most people use a `<ul>` for lists. Then you need to hide the `<li>`

Comment: @jalynn2 Can I add `<li>`elements from code behind?

Comment: +10000 for using a list in place of a table. It's both more semantic and works better!

Comment: If you mean with JavaScript/Jquery, yes you can use the .append() function to add them to the list

Comment: @jalynn2 No, I mean that the linkbuttons are created in `C#` I use only jQuery to hide the submenus.

Comment: Table for menu, are we still in the 90s ? Go for structured content like <ul><li></li></ul> or nested div with dedicated class that you can style with css.

Comment: I'm not a .asp programmer. There must be a way to create an unordered list, isn't there?

Comment: "The complete html code" Really? Where are the `.submenus` CSS classes. Also this is mainly a CSS question as the layout is usually set with CSS.

Comment: @feela submenus is not a really css class is just a class name I assign at code behind to each submenu in order to be hidden.

Comment: So, is the idea change my `td` `menuCell` by and `<ul>` and put dinamycally each linkbutton inside a `<li>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put each submenu inside an Asp.net panel:

```
Panel psubmenu = new Panel();
HyperLink hylSMenu = new HyperLink();
psubmenu.Controls.Add(hylSMenu);
```

An then put the Panel inside the whole container:

```
menuCell.Controls.Add(psubmenu);
```

Like this i toggle the `panel` instead of each submenu.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET will be handling code at the server side. Once the page has been loaded DOM can only be manipulated using Javascript or Javascript libraries such as jQuery.

Comment: can you share the html code with your menus? The html you have shared does not seem to be of Menus.

Comment: Yes is the whole code, the menus are **genereted dynamicaly at server side** and are placed into the `menucell` td.

Comment: Please share the generated code if you can, so i should help you with the code. Simpy copy paste it form your browser.